# Override Magento 2 core JS file Without affecting core functionilties

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, overrides, requirejs

I'm trying to override

> module-sales/view/adminhtml/web/order/create/scripts.js file.

Added the custom js file in my requirejs-config.js file. But the issue is, What all changes I made to in custom script.js file is reflecting in Magento core functionalities also, For example in order page. I need to reflect the changes in my custom module pages only. How to make it possible?

Please, can anyone help?

Comment: Did u get any solution for this?

Comment: @mani No. Im checking

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `custom.js` file in your module layout xml file like this:

```
<head>
    <script src=path/cutom.js"/>
</head>
```

And put only that which you needed for that module only other code move to default custom.js.

Answer (score 1):

I tried editing and overriding this file but was not able to find a proper way. As a workaround I created my  extra functionality in another prototype object and called it inside a phtml defined in the sales_order_create_index layout file.

**example:**

> Namespace/Module/view/adminhtml/web/js/customscript.js

```
define([
    "jquery",
    "Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal",
    "mage/loader",
    "mage/translate",
    "prototype",


], function (jQuery, modal,loader) {
    window.addProduct = Class.create();

    addProduct.prototype = {
      //Custom code
     initialize: function () {
            //Code to run on Object Initialisation
      },
      setPopUpContainer: function (trigger) {
            //Code to pull up a modal 

        },
        reloadAreas: function () {
          // this accesses the order object from the scripts.js file and reloads the various areas in the page
          order.loadArea(['items', 'shipping_method', 'totals', 'billing_method'], true);

        }


    };
});
```

> Namespace/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/custom-js.phtml

```
<script>
    require(["jquery", "prototype", "Magento_Sales/order/create/form", "Namespace_Module/js/customscript"], function ($) {

        window.CustomAddProduct = new addProduct();

    });



</script>
```

> Namespace/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>      
        <referenceContainer name="js"> 
            <block class="Namespace\Module\Block\Adminhtml\CustomBlock" template="Namespace_Module::custom-js.phtml" name="customblockname"/>

        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Hello Rohan, did you add require-config.js for that customscript.js? or add that script in head tag using  <link src="vendor_Module::js/customscript.js" />